# How to create a dictionary with a set of letters

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I have a set of letters as input param , and I have to create a dictionary[a set of words] with all the combination  set of letters . What would be the best algorithm/library to approach this in C++. I need maximal optimization possible .

The letters in the input stream are a-z and repeating in nature. I need a solution for a set of words of N length, which can be created by this.

Comment: I have tried the followed steps:
1> get the max count of words for an N length word. lets say an N length word has  a1 'a's, b1 'b's .......... z1 'z's..
such that a1+b1+....+z1=N.
in that case count= (N!)/((a1!)*(b1!)*.....*(z1!)).

2> In step 2 I will pick out chars from the input char stream randomly [not duplicated index] and will form an word of length N  which will be stored in a list. While adding an word into the list I will traverse the history of the list to eliminate duplicate entries.

3> This will give me a proper solution, but the runtime complexity is too high.

Comment: Does DAWG can help me out anyway in this case?